# Managing projects in Gogland

Tags: go, goland

I'm new in GO and need some help. I've got this structure of all my projects:

```
go_projects
-bin
-pkg
-src
--FirstProject
--SecondProject
```

Working in **Gogland Build #GO-171.3780.106, built on March 22, 2017** I like this autocompletion which is standart now for IDEs. But when I'm working with SecondProject - Gogland always show in list files from FirstProject and some of them has equal names. My **GOPATH** is **../go_projects**. Can I do something to exclude FirstProject modules from autocomplete for SecondProject and SecondProject from FirstProject??

Answer (score 0):

The project structure you are using is not a proper Go structure.
You should follow the instructions here: https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces for how to do that.
As for completion, the projects are part of the same GOPATH (when configured correctly) so it's normal to have them show in each-others completion mode. However, you can exclude them by using Settings | Go | Imports